# Packaging NodeJS along with electron application

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have an electron desktop application running.Is it possible to package it with nodejs server set up and make it as an complete application or and .exe file?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

Electron is already bundled with NodeJS. To package the app, install the [`electron-packager`](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager) module:

```
npm install -g electron-packager
```

And then package your app with:

```
electron-packager <sourcedir> --platform=<platform> --arch=<arch>
```

See the linked docs above for more details on how to do this.

Or you can save it to your package.json file and create a gulp task to run the packager.